# No such file or directory failed to open stream

Tags: php

Не удается задать правильный путь к файлу 
file(/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/site/sentences/feasible.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/site/main_page.php on line 229

```
$file_text = file("/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/site/sentences/$eng.txt");
```

Comment: А по какому пути лежит файл?\

Comment: в FileZila вот так /lenia/public_html/site/sentences

Answer (score 1):

Распечатай путь к текущему файлу что бы проверить корректность пути к главной директории

```
var_dump('__FILE__')
```

А путь так никогда не пиши, используй конкатенацию

```
$file_text = file("/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/site/sentences/" . $eng . ".txt");
```

Comment: вывело такой путь /home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html

Comment: я сделала так, и все равно не выходит file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/sentences/".$eng.".txt");

Comment: Судя по `file("/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/site/sentences/$eng.txt")`, значением `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` должно быть `"/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html`. Воспользуйтесь функцией `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/sentences/".$eng.".txt")`, чтобы посмотреть, какое значение у Вас получилось при конкатенации, и при необходимости скорректируйте код.

Comment: никаких отличий не вижу Warning: file(/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/sentences/negotiat.txt) от string(56) "/home/c/cd09875/lenia/public_html/sentences/negotiat.txt"

Comment: Значит файла действительно нет. Проверьте используемые символы, может где-то кирилица закралась в названии, протестируйте с другими файлами.